# するようにしてください vs. してください

Tags: grammar

> 市や町が避難の情報を出したら、できるだけ早く避難**するようにしてください**。

How is the construction するようにしてください different from してください? If we said "できるだけ早く避難してください," would it mean just the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vようにする is a common structure that adds a sense of "to make an effort to (do something) ".

So

> できるだけ早く避難するようにしてください。
>   Please make an effort to evacuate as fast as possible.

compared to

> できるだけ早く避難してください。
>   Please evacuate as fast as possible.